# 'jpeg_mem_src': identifier not found

Tags: libjpeg

I have tried to use   `jpeg_mem_src` using `libjpeg 6b`

```
  // seting memory buffer as source     
    jpeg_mem_src(&cinfo, jpg_buffer, jpg_size);
```

But I get the error:

> 'jpeg_mem_src': identifier not found

I have downloaded "Binaries", "Dependencies", "Developer files" from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/jpeg.htm

I work in visual studio 2015 and included the included folder and added additional libraries. So other functions work, but as for `jpeg_mem_src`- it is an error.

Can you tell me, please, where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I meet the error when compiling [cwi-pcl-codec-1ed743](https://github.com/cwi-dis/cwi-pcl-codec/tree/1ed743d8687dc645fc865fb454f7cc76bdbc9774).
I update ibjpeg-turbo64 version form 1.5.0 to 2.0.2.
It works.